How can I create a reusable `service` definition across my github actions?
I have a project with multiple microservices, relying on a central database. Each microservice lives in a separate Github repository with its own pipeline. The pipeline definition for each of them looks more or less like this:
# validate.yaml

  ...
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql/mysql:8
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: some_db
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: some_pw
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
    steps:
      # init database
      - run: a number
      - run: of steps to
      - run: initialise the db
      - run: with test data that
      - is the same for each microservice
      # run tests for microservice
      - run: poetry run pytest


Is it possible to define the mysql service, as well as its setup steps in a generic way, so that I can re-use it in all of my different repositories?

You can create a resusable workflow in one repository and then reference it in  your microservice workflows.
check out this article: https://dev.to/quartztechnology/use-reusable-workflows-to-push-images-on-github-actions-2a17

I read about that, but I thought it was to re-use a complete job or jobs, not a part of it?
